# insert paragraph with pillow python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, format, python-imaging-library

Let's say I have a given string

`x = "testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing"`

Then using Pillow, I want to insert that as a paragraph onto an image with an invisible box to guide the text into the correctly formatted place. The "invisible" boxes are outlined in white in the image I will attach. Refer to
[Image with outlined boxes for x to go into.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr2iD.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to my problem was a simple text wrap by python 3.8's textwrap feature. Now placing the wrapped text with a delimiter of 50 throws it all in a neatly wrapped paragraph.